# Navigation Bar on Scrollview bartint not on top

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

I'm working on a project, where I have multiple views on a scrollview.
I can scroll through them horizontally. It works nice!
But I've got a problem with the navigationbars in each views I added to the scrollview.
[image]
They are on it (as you can see from the screenshot), but the navigationbar on the top is not filling out everything from the top. 
There's this white space, I don't want to have. I would like to have this space in the same blue as the navigationbar has.

Now my question, how can I achieve this?

I added the views with following code to the scrollview:

```
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let profilView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profilController") as! UIViewController
    self.addChildViewController(profilView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(profilView.view)
    profilView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    profilView.view.frame = scrollView.bounds

    let testViewTwo = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatController") as! UIViewController
    self.addChildViewController(testViewTwo)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(testViewTwo.view)
    testViewTwo.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    testViewTwo.view.frame = scrollView.bounds

    var frame:CGRect = testViewTwo.view.frame
    frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    testViewTwo.view.frame = frame

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 2, height: self.view.frame.height)

    //startposition
    //self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: (self.view.frame.width) * 1, y: self.view.frame.height)
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Navigation Bar Height to 64 and place it "behind" the Status Bar.

[Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XZsu.png)